# app.onactivated not firing depending on placement of app.start()

Tags: windows-8, winjs

My understanding of the `WinJS.Application.start()` function is that it allows WinJS to queue up certain normal page initialization events to give you a chance to set up other data first in your `default.js` file. By calling the `start()` function at the end of `default.js`, WinJS then fires off all the queued events for you (such as the `activated` event).

I'm trying to understand where everything fits in the life cycle, so I'm not clear why the first of the following examples works but the second doesn't. All I'm doing is updating the page title, which doesn't work as expected when I call `app.start()` after a 5-second delay:

First, here's `default.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script references...>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="pageTitle">Page of coolness...</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's the first `default.js` example (which works as expected):

```
(function () {

    var app = WinJS.Application;

    app.onactivated = function () {
            document.getElementById("pageTitle").innerText = "Rock it!";
    };

    // This code *does* fire the onactivated event:
    //   The page displays "Rock it!" in the page title
    app.start();

})();
```

Here's the second `default.js` example (which doesn't work as expected):

```
(function () {

    var app = WinJS.Application;

    app.onactivated = function () {
            document.getElementById("pageTitle").innerText = "Rock it!";
    };

    // This code *doesn't* fire the onactivated event:
    //   It initially displays "Page of coolness..." in the page title.
    //   After 5 seconds, it adds "Gettin' there...Almost made it..." 
    //   to the the page title, but "Rock it!" never gets displayed
    WinJS.Promise.timeout(5000).then(function () {
        document.getElementById("pageTitle").innerText += "Gettin' there...";
        app.start();
        document.getElementById("pageTitle").innerText += "Almost made it...";
    });
})();
```

Why does calling `app.start()` after the 5-second delay cause the `activated` event not to fire?

Comment: not an answer, but onloaded does fire. You can walk through base.js in the debugger, and you'll see a difference sequence executed. It's almost as if the activated event handler gets attached 'too late', so when it fires, it hasn't yet been attached and is null, but can't explain why or if that's appropriate behavior.

Comment: @Jim _"It's almost as if the activated event handler gets attached 'too late', so when it fires, it hasn't yet been attached and is null..."_...turns out that is exactly what is happening, and it looks like it is that way by design (though I couldn't tell why)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for the `start` function is a little misleading.

When you call `start`, `WinJS.Application` begins to queue and dispatch events, including those which are emitted by `Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication`. One of these events is `activated`, which is what leads to your handler function being called.

The important point is that the queuing doesn't begin until you call `start`. Any events that are emitted by `WebUIApplication` before the queuing begins are lost forever.

This is the situation you have created by delaying your call to `start`: the `activated` event is sent by `WebUIApplication` before the `WinJS.Application` queue has been set up. The `activated` event is never received by `WinJS.Application` and so your handler function is never invoked.

I know you are just trying to figure out the life cycle, but there isn't a reason to delay your call to the `start` function in real life. The only way to get the effect you are trying to create in your code is to place the Promise inside the `onactivated` handler function, like this:

```
(function () {

    var app = WinJS.Application;

    app.onactivated = function () {
        document.getElementById("pageTitle").innerText += "Gettin' there...";

        WinJS.Promise.timeout(5000).then(function () {
            document.getElementById("pageTitle").innerText = "Rock it!";
        });
        document.getElementById("pageTitle").innerText += "Almost made it...";

    };

    app.start();
})();
```

Comment: I finally decided to venture inside `base.js`, which I had been hesitating to do. It looks like the `WinJS.Application` queue does get set up before the call to `start()`, but since `start()` is where the event handler for the `Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.activated` event gets attached, and this handler is what queues up the `WinJS.Application.activated` event, then delaying the call to `start()` prevents the `Windows.UI.WebUI.WebUIApplication.activated` event from being handled (since its handler gets attached after the event fires--which is right after `default.js` finishes). Thank you

Comment: "there isn't a reason to delay your call to the start function in real life" - disagree